# How to show an image inside a non-editable JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield

In my Java Swing application i want to put a lock image inside a JTextField that is not editable, to appear like this :

[image: Locked JTextField]

I have created a JTextField, and inserted a JLabel above it and defined the lock icon for the JLabel. If the JTextField is editable then the JLabel appears fine as the image above shows, but if the JTextField is not editable then the image does not appear at all.

**How can i fix that ?**

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).
Generate a small image in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add both label (for icon) and the textfield in a panel. Remove border from the textfield and add a common border around the panel. Set background to be the same as the textfield's background.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the nice solutions. That was the simplest for me. The final component looked very nice. Thanks StanislavL.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use a jTextPane ?

```
try {
    // Get the text pane's document
    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument)textPane.getDocument();

    // The image must first be wrapped in a style
    Style style = doc.addStyle("StyleName", null);
    StyleConstants.setIcon(style, new ImageIcon("imagefile"));

    // Insert the image at the end of the text
    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "ignored text", style);
} catch (BadLocationException e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write own Class that extends `JTextField` and inside this class you have to overide `paintComponent(Graphics g)`

1) carefully with positions for `Icon`

because

2) put your `Custom JTextField` to the resizibale `Container`, try if `Icon` stay still on right side, if resize works correctly for `Custom JTextField` with `Icon` inside,

3) create constructor for `setEditable(true)` and  `setEditable(false)` with `Icon`

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom `Border` lets call it IconBorder. Take a look at the source code for MatteIcon and then customize it to only paint a single image. Then you would add the Border to the text field with code like:

```
Border border = new CompoundBorder(textField.getBorder(), new IconBorder(...));
textField.setBorder( border );
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Java 7? Then use a [JLayeredPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html).